# "Simple PHP and MySqli Login Form Not Working"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I created a login and register form, though I'm able to insert into the database successfully on the Register form, but when it comes to the login form its not working(it doesn't go onto the next page) and it is not displaying any error. Where do I need to set right?

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $customerid = $_POST['customerid'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // processing remember me option and setting cookie with long expiry date
    if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
        session_set_cookie_params('604800'); //one week (value in seconds)
        session_regenerate_id(true);
    }

    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    # check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
        exit();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE customer_id ='$customerid' AND password = '$password' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        die($mysqli->error);
    }
    if ($result->num_rows != 1) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Wrong Customer ID or Password!")';
        echo '</script>';
        echo "<div><h6 align='center' style='color: red;'>Wrong Customer ID or Password!</h6></div>";
    } else {
        // Authenticated, set session variables
        $user = $result->fetch_array();
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['customer_id'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email'];

        // update status to online
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET log_status= '$timestamp' WHERE customer_id={$_SESSION['user_id']}";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

        redirect_to("dashboard.php?id={$_SESSION['user_id']}");
        // do stuffs
    }
}
```

its supposed to login into the dashboard

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I really hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library to get the same functionality.

Comment: `Die()`-ing is not a proper way to control the flow of your script!

Comment: What is `redirect_to` doing exactly?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but its still not working

Comment: You'll need to call `exit;` in your `redirect_to` function instead of `return;` Otherwise the header will be sent, but unable to redirect due to the page content being sent along with it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try the following login script, modify defines as needed,  but please, look into PDO/MySQLi prepared statements as specified to prevent sql injection as well as the the built in function `password_hash` to prevent malicious users seeing the actual password in the database - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

```
<?php

    define('DB_HOST', 'host');
    define('DB_USER', 'pass');
    define('DB_PASS', '');
    define('DB_NAME', 'dbname');

    function redirect_to($location){
        header("Location: $location");
        exit;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

        $customerid = $_POST['customerid'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // processing remember me option and setting cookie with long expiry date
        if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
            session_set_cookie_params('604800'); //one week (value in seconds)
            session_regenerate_id(true);
        }

        $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        # check connection
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
            exit();
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE customer_id ='$customerid' AND password = '$password' LIMIT 1";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
        if (!$result) {
            die($mysqli->error);
        }
        if ($result->num_rows != 1) {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Wrong Customer ID or Password!")';
            echo '</script>';
            echo "<div><h6 align='center' style='color: red;'>Wrong Customer ID or Password!</h6></div>";
        } else {
            // Authenticated, set session variables
            $user = $result->fetch_array();
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['customer_id'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email'];

            // update status to online
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET log_status= '$timestamp' WHERE customer_id={$_SESSION['user_id']}";
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

            redirect_to("dashboard.php?id={$_SESSION['user_id']}");
            // do stuffs
        }
    }
?>

<form method="POST">
    Username<input name="customerid"></input>
    Password<input type="password" name="password"></input>
    <input name="login" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Comment: `mysqli` supports [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) as well.

Comment: You'll need to call `exit;` in your `redirect_to` function instead of `return;` Otherwise the header will be sent, but unable to redirect due to the page content being sent along with it

Comment: Please clarify if I use return after header on an external redirect that this is still the case?   I have yet to test on an internal redirect.

Comment: It pertains to all `header()` calls. If you send body content with your response, the `Location:` header will be invalidated. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php Demonstrating the use of `exit` and the warning about the code below being executed. The exception would be when us output buffering, and clearing the body content [`ob_end_clean()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php) before the `header()` call.

Comment: Insertion of a second header command or any other php code (second header) invalidated the first. But,  a simple redirect with no php command, and no prior exit, following, produced desired result.

Comment: It depends greatly on PHP and webserver configuration. It may work as desired in your environment, but it is known to cause issues without using `exit`  For example php-fpm and apache mod_php behave differently. In my environment I can not generate the *headers already sent* error when using `<html><?php header('Location: example.com'); ?>` as described in the PHP manual

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what the redirect_to is for, but try this instead:

`header(“Location: dashboard.php?id={$_SESSION['user_id']}”);`

Comment: I think you need " when working with curly braces to wrap variables, right? In addition, there is an extra space in front of `{`. It should be: `header("Location: dashboard.php?id={$_SESSION['user_id']}");`

Comment: Fair enough. What I probably should have said was use header() instead of redirect_to

Comment: Can you edit your answer please in order to provide a working example? Furthermore, wrap your code in ` ` please.

Comment: i tried using header() Function but its still not working

Comment: When you say there are no errors, what does it do when you register?